# Adding block element to a custom grid

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a page with 6 blocks like

```
block 1                   block 5
block 2
block 3                   block 6
block 4
```

here block 1 and block 5 are grid with same position.
So i want a page like this so i tried

```
.item-list ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.2em 0.5em 0 0;
}

.block-5 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 460px !important;
    margin-top: -1681px !important;
}
```

My issue is if I add another block below block 4 say block 7, View page display will disorder, then again i want to change `margin-top: -1681px !important;` position. How can i fix this issue? Please help.

Comment: can you please add your html.

Answer (score 1):

What you require is a solid solution and it is provided by CSS Grid. I have added the additional block 7 and explained it through CSS comments. You can play with the [**Grid Generator**](https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.com/).

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

.area1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}

.area2 {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}

.area3 {
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2;
}

.area4 {
  grid-area: 4 / 1 / 5 / 2;
}

.area5 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}

.area6 {
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 3;
}

/* Additional Block */

.area7 {
  grid-area: 5 / 1 / 6 / 2; /* Start at Row 5, Start at Column 1, Stop at Row 6, Stop at Column 2 */
}

/* Unrequired Snippet Styling */
div[class^="area"]{
  background: #5548B0;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="area1">Block 1</div>
  <div class="area2">Block 2</div>
  <div class="area3">Block 3</div>
  <div class="area4">Block 4</div>
  <div class="area5">Block 5</div>
  <div class="area6">Block 6</div>
  <!-- Additional Block -->
  <div class="area7">Additional Block 7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can't define the position in this way, isn't stable.

You need to split you block in column, then the top block of each column remain aligned in top.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div>block 1</div>
    <div>block 2</div>
    <div>block 3</div>
    <div>block 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div>block 5</div>
    <div>block 6</div>  
  </div>
</div>

// css

.row{
  display:flex;
}

.col{
  flex-grow:1
}
```

Here a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/x2ohrwan/1/

Comment: I will explain why someone down voted you. There is a gap between Block 5 and 6.

Comment: Thank you, yes I know, if the gap have a custom height you can do it by just adding margin-top to block6, otherwise if block6 need to be aligned to block 3 you need two row, one with block 1-2-5 and one with the other.